# Kafka Connect S3 sink - how to use the timestamp from the message itself [timestamp extractor]

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've been struggling with a problem using kafka connect and the S3 sink.

First the structure:

```
{
   Partition: number
   Offset: number
   Key: string
   Message: json string
   Timestamp: timestamp
}
```

Normally when posting to Kafka, the timestamp should be set by the producer. Unfortunately there seems to be cases where this didn't happen. This means that the Timestamp might sometimes be `null`

To extract this timestamp the connector was set to the following value:
`"timestamp.extractor":"Record"`.

Now it is always certain that the `Message` field itself always contains a timestamp as well.

`Message`:

```
{
   timestamp: "2019-04-02T06:27:02.667Z"
   metadata: {
     creationTimestamp: "1554186422667"
   }
}
```

The question however is that now, I would like to use that field for the `timestamp.extractor`

I was thinking that this would suffice, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
"timestamp.extractor":"RecordField",
"timestamp.field":"message.timestamp",
```

This results in a NullPointer as well.

Any ideas as to how to use the timestamp from the kafka message payload itself, instead of the default timestamp field that is set for kafka v0.10+

EDIT:
Full config:

```
{ "name": "<name>",
  "config": {
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"4",
    "topics":"<topic>",
    "flush.size":"100",
    "s3.bucket.name":"<bucket name>",
    "s3.region": "<region>",
    "s3.part.size":"<partition size>",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms":"86400000",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "storage.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
    "locale":"ENGLISH",
    "timezone":"UTC",
    "schema.generator.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.TimeBasedSchemaGenerator",
    "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
    "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd",
    "timestamp.extractor":"RecordField",
    "timestamp.field":"message.timestamp",
    "max.poll.interval.ms": "600000",
    "request.timeout.ms": "610000",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "6000",
    "session.timeout.ms": "20000",
    "s3.acl.canned":"bucket-owner-full-control"
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Kafka message payload structure:

```
{
  "reference": "",
  "clientId": "",
  "gid": "",
  "timestamp": "2019-03-19T15:27:55.526Z",
}
```

EDIT 3:

```
{
"transforms": "convert_op_creationDateTime",
"transforms.convert_op_creationDateTime.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.convert_op_creationDateTime.target.type": "Timestamp",
"transforms.convert_op_creationDateTime.field": "timestamp",
"transforms.convert_op_creationDateTime.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
}
```

So I tried doing a transform on the object, but it seems like I've been stuck again on this thing. The pattern seems to be invalid. Looking around the internet it does seem like this is a valid SimpleDatePattern. It seems to be complaining about the `'T'`. Updated the message schema as well.

Comment: To clarify: you're using Kafka Connect as a sink? And using Single Message Transform to extract the timestamp of the Kafka message into a field of the message you want to write to the sink? Can you share your full Kafka Connect config?

Comment: Updated the message!

Comment: OK this is making more sense now :) Can you share the schema of your message please?

Comment: Do you mean this property? `Message: json string`?

Comment: Could you show the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the schema you've shared, you should be setting:

```
    "timestamp.extractor":"RecordField",
    "timestamp.field":"timestamp",
```

i.e. no `message` prefix to the timestamp field name.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fully work though. Still getting a nullpointer on it. Eventhough the message actually has the timestamp available (according to kafka tools)

Comment: Might it be related to it being UTC? Does it need to be transformed someway?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is a string, then Connect will try to parse as **milliseconds** - [source code here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/TimeBasedPartitioner.java#L309).

In any case, `message.timestamp` assumes the data looks like `{ "message" : { "timestamp": ... } }`, so just `timestamp` would be correct. And having nested fields didn't use to be possible anyway, so you might want to clarify which version of Connect you have.

I'm not entirely sure how you would get `instanceof Date` to evalutate to true when using JSON Converter, and even if you had set `schema.enable = true`, then also in the code, you can see there is only conditions for schema types of numbers and strings, but still assumes that it is milliseconds.

You can try using the [TimestampConverter](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html#timestampconverter) transformation to convert your date string.

Comment: It seems like I'm hitting a wall here. I've updated the question with some more information. I did notice I had access to a normal timestamp as well, which afaik would be perfect for the "string" format time. Would it help using a ExtractField or something related for this?

Comment: Not sure why you need to extract anything. I haven't used the TimestampConverter myself because the data I work with is almost always unix epoch time in milliseconds. The unit tests for it are here, though, if you wanted to take a look https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/TimestampConverterTest.java